# Removing extra space after itemize environment in longtable in memoir

Tags: spacing, lists, memoir, longtable

I have a macro that creates itemize environment in it.
The issue is that I have extra space after the itemize environment when used in longtable. 
How to remove the space?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\fuda}[2]{%
Functions:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#1%
\end{itemize}
Data:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#2%
\end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}}
\caption[List of components]{List of functions and data allocated to each component} \label{d_plan} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Components} & \textbf{Functions and Data} \\\midrule
\textbf{Registration} & \fuda{
\item Register capabilities of the device
\item Unregister capabilities of the device
\item Register context representation 
}{
\item  Interface List 
\item Capability List
\item  Protocol List
\item Representation List}
\\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### ADDED

The solution that uses `-\baselineskip:` works with article class, but not with memoir class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `p` column entry in a table ends with essentially

```
\unskip \strut \par \egroup \hfil
```

so after your list you get a `\strut` added which appears on a newline.  You can back-up with `-\baselineskip`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\fuda}[2]{%
Functions:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#1%
\end{itemize}
Data:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#2%
\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}}
\caption[List of components]{List of functions and data allocated to each component} \label{d_plan} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Components} & \textbf{Functions and Data} \\\midrule
\textbf{Registration} &\fuda{\item Register capabilities of the device
\item Unregister capabilities of the device
\item Register context representation 
}{\item  Interface List 
\item Capability List
\item  Protocol List
\item Representation List}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The same applies to `p` cells in ordinary tables.

*Added* in the `memoir` class the definition of `\@endpbox` is a little difference and you will need to write

```
 \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\leavevmode
```

instead of just the `\vspace*` command.

Comment: This solution works with article, but with memoir it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\fuda}[2]{%
Functions:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#1%
\end{itemize}
Data:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#2%
\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}}
\caption[List of components]{List of functions and data allocated to each component} \label{d_plan} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Components} & \textbf{Functions and Data} \\\midrule
\textbf{Registration} &\fuda{\item Register capabilities of the device
\item Unregister capabilities of the device
\item Register context representation 
}{\item  Interface List 
\item Capability List
\item  Protocol List
\item Representation List}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}
\\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use a `minipage`.

```
\newcommand{\fuda}[2]{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
Functions:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#1%
\end{itemize}
Data:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#2%
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\fuda}[2]{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
Functions:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#1%
\end{itemize}
Data:%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
#2%
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}}
\caption[List of components]{List of functions and data allocated to each component} \label{d_plan} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Components} & \textbf{Functions and Data} \\\midrule
\textbf{Registration} &\fuda{\item Register capabilities of the device
\item Unregister capabilities of the device
\item Register context representation
}{\item  Interface List
\item Capability List
\item  Protocol List
\item Representation List}
\\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]